# 1046: type was not found not a compile-time constant: NewsItem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

i'm having trouble this errors keep comeup :

1046: type was not found not a compile-time constant: NewsItem
1108: call to a possibly undefined

my actions is :

```
var newsContainer:Sprite = new Sprite;
addChild(newsContainer);

var newsArray:Array = new Array( );

for(var k:Number=0;k<0;k++) {

    var newsItem:NewsItem = new NewsItem;

    newsArray.push(newsItem);
    newsContainer.addChild(newsItem);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `import` the `NewsItem` class.

An import statement follows the structure:

```
import path.path.Class
```

Where the path begins from the location of the .fla file. For example, if you have a folder `compile` in the same directory as your .fla and it contains a class `MyClass`, the import statement would be:

```
import compile.MyClass;
```

Comment: shall i replace the Class with my class name

Comment: ^^^^^ ?!! shall i replace the Class with my class name